# Show push notification in background mode - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, push

I'm using the connectivity_plus plugin to check the internet connection. Is there any way to display offline notification when App is in background? i try workmanager, but the minimum interval between two periodic work request is 15 min.

Is there any way to use or listen from firebase to display notification in background mode?

main.dart

```
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutterfcm/conectivity.dart';

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', 'High Importance Notifications',
    description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
    importance: Importance.high,
    playSound: true);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  runApp(MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Map _source = {ConnectivityResult.none: false};
  final MyConnectivity _connectivity = MyConnectivity.instance;
  List<Widget> widgetList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _connectivity.initialise();
    _connectivity.myStream.listen((source) {
      setState(() => _source = source);
      if (_source.keys.first == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        showNotification();

        setState(() {
          widgetList.add(Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Card(
                elevation: 3,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('No internet in:'),
                      Text(
                        DateTime.now().toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.amber, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
          ));
        });
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channelDescription: channel.description,
                color: Colors.blue,
                playSound: true,
                icon: '@mipmap/ic_lancher',
              ),
            ));
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text("${notification.title}"),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [Text("${notification.body}")],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
      }
    });
  }

  void showNotification() {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0,
        'OFFLINE',
        'No internet available',
        NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(channel.id, channel.name,
                channelDescription: channel.description,
                importance: Importance.high,
                color: Colors.blue,
                playSound: true,
                icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher')));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Notifications"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: widgetList,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

conectivity.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';

class MyConnectivity {
  MyConnectivity._();

  static final _instance = MyConnectivity._();
  static MyConnectivity get instance => _instance;
  final _connectivity = Connectivity();
  final _controller = StreamController.broadcast();
  Stream get myStream => _controller.stream;

  void initialise() async {
    ConnectivityResult result = await _connectivity.checkConnectivity();
    _checkStatus(result);
    _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((result) {
      _checkStatus(result);
    });
  }

  void _checkStatus(ConnectivityResult result) async {
    bool isOnline = false;
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      isOnline = result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty;
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      isOnline = false;
    }
    _controller.sink.add({result: isOnline});
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you `listen from firebase` when there is no connection ?

Comment: I only use it locally, but I need it to display notifications in background mode.